# SwiftUI not detecting dark mode from setting

Tags: swift, swiftui

In SwiftUI on my device, I set the appearance to dark mode. However, my application doesn't change the background colour based on that appearance. For the color asset, I have set the values for both the light and dark appearance, like so

[image]

In my code this is how I set the background color and static variable,

```
extension Color {
  static let backgroundColor = Color("Background")
}

..... // In my View 
        ZStack {
        Color.backgroundColor
            .ignoresSafeArea()
        ......
        }
```

Also when I debug and check

```
@Environment (\.colorScheme) var colorScheme:ColorScheme
```

it returns that my device is indeed on dark mode. Any idea what is going on and why I'm unable to activate dark mode automatically from the user's device preferences.

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: @loremipsum That is a minimal reproducible example. I told you how I set the background and the issue with it.

Comment: No it isn’t . You aren’t showing the setup for your static variable. The issue is likely there. Typos are the number one cause of this.

Comment: @loremipsum Fair enough, just added

Comment: Try changing the name to something other than Background, I don’t see anything obvious but sometimes when you have names like that they can cause issues because of system references

Comment: Are you sure your `Color` view is not entirely overlaid by another view?

Comment: It's not because if I change it to Color.red it appears perfectly fine. @Sulthan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out when you use

```
.preferredColorScheme(.light | .dark)
```

It applies that preference to the entire view rather than the element the property is being used on.

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine on simulator and device:

```
struct ColorSchemeView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        Color.backgroundColor
            .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}

fileprivate extension Color {
    static let backgroundColor = Color("DarkLight")
}
```

I suspect you have some other issue in the code that will need a true [Minimal Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to debug.